# std::copy for multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

I've tried the other day with `gcc-4.9.1`:

```
int main()
{
  int a[10][20][30];
  int b[10][20][30];

  ::std::copy(::std::begin(a), ::std::end(a), ::std::begin(b));

  return 0;
}
```

and, of course, it produced an error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:39,
                 from t.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static _Tp* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = int [20][30]; bool _IsMove = false]':
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:396:70:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = int (*)[20][30]; _OI = int (*)[20][30]]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:434:38:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = int (*)[20][30]; _OI = int (*)[20][30]]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:466:17:   required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = int (*)[20][30]; _OI = int (*)[20][30]]'
t.cpp:10:62:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:373:4: error: static assertion failed: type is not assignable
    static_assert( is_copy_assignable<_Tp>::value,
    ^
```

I think this is not so much a problem with `std::copy()`, as with `std::begin()` and `std::end()` that would handle multidimensional arrays. Is this an omission with the current C++ standard and how to work around it?

EDIT: I am convinced, the standard could fix this problem:

```
namespace std
{

template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
constexpr typename remove_all_extents<T>::type*
begin(T (&array)[M][N])
{
  return begin(array[0]);
}

template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
constexpr typename remove_all_extents<T>::type*
end(T (&array)[M][N])
{
  return end(array[M - 1]);
}

}
```

Comment: It's an omission (but I'd guess, largely an intentional one). Work around it by not using arrays of arrays.

Comment: Using `std::array` instead of plain arrays would solve the problem.

Comment: @Zyx2000 Why are multidimensional arrays consistently neglected? Yes, `std::array` could also help, but array types are a part of C++, just like `std::array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work with a simple `copy` call as plain arrays cannot be copied or assigned. However, you can copy the underlying elements and treat the multidimensional array as a one-dimensional one.

One convenient possibility is to use a flattened range accessors:

```
// For convenient trailing-return-types in C++11:
#define AUTO_RETURN(...) \
 noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) {return (__VA_ARGS__);}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto decayed_begin(T&& c)
AUTO_RETURN(std::begin(std::forward<T>(c)))

template <typename T>
constexpr auto decayed_end(T&& c)
AUTO_RETURN(std::end(std::forward<T>(c)))

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto decayed_begin(T(&c)[N])
AUTO_RETURN(reinterpret_cast<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*>(c    ))

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto decayed_end(T(&c)[N])
AUTO_RETURN(reinterpret_cast<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*>(c + N))
```

Then,

```
std::copy( decayed_begin(a), decayed_end(a), decayed_begin(b) );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1b6069e28e1426).

Comment: wow, actually I am more interested in the AUTO_RETURN trick, than in your solution. Where did you come by it?

Comment: Isn't `__VA_ARGS__` still non-standard though?

Comment: @user1095108 No, it's standard since C++11. [cpp.subst]/2: "An identifier `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list shall be treated as if it were a parameter, and the variable arguments shall form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it."

Comment: @user1095108 `noexcept` is a standardized keyword, yes. It wouldn't make sense here though since no `std::begin` overload is declared `noexcept`.

Comment: That's true, but your `decayed_*` functions are not standard. Ahh, I see, it is because of forwarding, fine.

Comment: @user1095108 I added `noexcept` to the definition of `AUTO_RETURN`.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have no assignment operator. So you need to copy the whole array element by element of type int.

For example you can write

```
std::copy( reinterpret_cast<int *>( a ),
           reinterpret_cast<int *>( a ) + 10 * 20 * 30,
           reinterpret_cast<int *>( b ) );
```

Or you can use `std::for_each` or `std::transform` with some compound lambda expressions.

Comment: Yeah, but the `reinterpret_cast` is ugliness incarnate, don't you agree?

Comment: @user1095108 It is the simplest way to copy multidimensional arrays.

Comment: If you can, explain what alternative there might be, the cast solution is generic (it would be even better, if you used the `sizeof` operator), but the `for_each` solution is not.

Comment: `memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(a));`

Comment: @jrok What if the elements aren't trivially copyable?

Comment: @user1095108 Then you use `boost::multi_array` :)

Comment: @jrok Obviously, that's not always possible either.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's easy to templatize your approach to benefit from automatic deduction of dimension size.

Comment: @Christophe I have just templatized another function.:)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948596/is-a-sorting-algorithm-worth-implementing-here/26949734#26949734

Answer (score 3):

Here another template variant, which works for **any multimensional array**, whatever the number of dimensions.  It uses the fact that elements of a multidimensional are contiguous and casting to process the array as if it was a flat one dimensional one:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type* mbegin(T& arr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*>(&arr);
}
template <typename T>
size_t msize(const T& a) 
{
    return sizeof(T) / sizeof(typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type);
}
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type* mend(T& arr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*>(&arr)+msize(arr);
}
```

You call it:

```
::std::copy(mbegin(a), mend(a), mbegin(b));
```

The trick here is to use the type T for the multidimensional array (`int[][]..[]`) and use `typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type` to remove the dimensions and get the base type (`int`).

Answer (score 2):

After reading through all the answers, here's my 5 cents, that seem to work:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T* begin(T& value) noexcept
{
  return &value;
}

template <typename T, ::std::size_t N>
constexpr typename ::std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*
begin(T (&array)[N]) noexcept
{
  return begin(array[0]);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T* end(T& value) noexcept
{
  return &value + 1;
}

template <typename T, ::std::size_t N>
constexpr typename ::std::remove_all_extents<T>::type*
end(T (&array)[N]) noexcept
{
  return end(array[N - 1]);
}
```

I won't accept my own answer and, if something is wrong, downvote or comment and I'll remove.

Comment: This answer is interesting. I tested it but observed that it copies only a couple of elements and not the full table.  This is because `sizeof(array)/sizeof(T)` is only applied to the outer dimension of the array (10 elements).

Comment: @Christophe Does it work now? I really wanted to avoid all those ugly casts.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has already found some very interesting answers.  Most are based on the fact that the C++ standard ensures that elements of a multidimensional array are **contiguous**, making it possible (via casting) to process the array as if it was a one dimensional one.

I propose this variant for the sake of completeness.  It uses templates and automatic deduction of array size:

```
template <typename T, size_t N1, size_t N2, size_t N3>
T* begin(T(&arr)[N1][N2][N3]) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr);  
}
template <typename T, size_t N1, size_t N2, size_t N3>
T* end (T(&arr)[N1][N2][N3]) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr)+N1*N2*N3;
```

You can then proceed with the copy:

```
::std::copy(begin(a), end(a), begin(b));
```

Another approach could be to define a 3D **iterator** using the same template approach.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a union with a flattened version.

```
int main()
{
  union
  {
    int a[10][20][30];
    int fa[10 * 20 * 30];
  };

  union
  {
    int b[10][20][30];
    int fb[10 * 20 * 30];
  };

  ::std::copy(::std::begin(fa), ::std::end(fa), ::std::begin(fb));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice hack. But not always useful.