# Is a sorting-algorithm worth implementing here?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a list of positive integers, and I want to store the 3 biggest values in the variables `h1`, `h2`, and `h3`. The remaining values are irrelevant.

I considered managing them with an `int*` and `realloc`ating memory as it is filled, followed by a suitable sorting algorithm, but is it really worth it? Since I don't really need to sort the entire array, I just did it like this:

```
if (currentVal > h3) {
    h3 = currentVal;
    if (currentVal > h2) {
        h3 = h2;
        h2 = currentVal;
        if (currentVal > h1) {
            h2 = h1;
            h1 = currentVal;
        }
    }
}
```

It feels like a dumb and static way of doing it, but it works. Should I implement a sorting algorithm instead, and if yet, any suggestion what might be suitable?

Comment: What's actually wrong using `std::sort()` for you?

Comment: No need to sort. It's ok doing like that. (Although if the list is short enough, sorting is more handy indeed than reinventing the wheel)

Comment: Since you only store 3 values the overhead of a sort may be longer than your code.  Look at the assembly language listing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For "top 3", that's perfectly reasonable. For "top k" with a larger (but fixed) value for `k`, you might want to try using a [priority queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Answer (score 2):

You can find any number of maximum elements in an array the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

template <size_t N> 
void n_max_element( const int a[],
                    size_t n,
                    std::array<int, N> &nmax )
{
    std::partial_sort_copy( a, a + n, 
                            nmax.begin(), nmax.end(), 
                            std::greater<int>() );
}   

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::random_shuffle( a, a + N );

    std::array<int, 3> max;

    n_max_element( a, N, max );

    std::cout << "max[0] = " << max[0] 
              << ", max[1] = " << max[1] 
              << ", max[2] = " << max[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
max[0] = 9, max[1] = 8, max[2] = 7
```